# How to use LocalStorage on last input value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

How can I set/retrieve the last input value with JavaScript or jquery? I'm trying to create an onkey function on a input value that that sets the input value, and then on each page-load, that valued is loaded.

```html
<input type="number" class="Number">
```

Comment: Is the php tag relevant?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Number").keyup(function () {
            var number = $(this).val();
            localStorage.setItem('number', number);
        });
        $('.Number').focus();
        $('.Number').val(localStorage.getItem("number")).focus().select();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="Number">
```